# Stand-alone scrollable tabs outside the header

Tags: material-design-lite

Does MDL have stand-alone scrollable tabs (i.e. **not part of the header**)? If the feature is available, I'm looking for the code example.

MDL has [scrollable tabs](http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section/layout) in the header but the [stand-alone tabs](http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section/tabs) seem to be missing the scrollable version. On the other hand, Polymer's `paper-tabs` has the [scrollable version](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-tabs?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-tabs) I'm looking for, but I can't use Polymer in my work.